# Inserting elements into array

Tags: java

I have a class that implements an interface and I think when I try to insert an element into the array more than once the first insertions are forgotten. I really can't figure this one out. This is what I have:

```
public void insertElementAt(int index, E el)
                 throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Object temp[] = new Object[data.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i == index){
            temp[index] = el;
            temp[i + 1] = data[i];
            i++;
        }

        temp[i] = data[i];
    }

    data = temp;

    if (index > data.length || index < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Then my test reports `null` instead of first at he last assertion.

```
@Test
public void testInsertToLeft() {
    PriorityList<String> list = new ArrayPriorityList<String>();
    list.insertElementAt(0, "First");
    // Must shift array elements in this case
    list.insertElementAt(0, "New First");

    assertEquals("New First", list.getElementAt(0));
    assertEquals("First", list.getElementAt(1));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need _two_ indexes - one for the old array and one for the new array. As it stands, when you skip along one element because of the insert you skip along _both_ arrays. P.S. just use a `List`.

Comment: it seems you need a `continue` at the end of `if` block.

Comment: What is the first size of `data`?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an `ArrayList`=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do like this:

```
public void insertElementAt(int index, E el) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Object temp[] = new Object[data.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i >= index){
            temp[i + 1] = data[i];
        } else {
            temp[i] = data[i];
        }
    }
    temp[index] = el;
    data = temp;

    if (index > data.length || index < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

To remove it:

```
public void removeElementAt(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    Object temp[] = new Object[data.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        if (i > index){
            temp[i - 1] = data[i];
        } else {
            temp[i] = data[i];
        }
    }
    data = temp;

    if (index > data.length || index < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured there was an easy fix without changing too much of his existing code (But I couldn't seem to figure it out), nice answer +1.

Comment: perfect. would I do something similar to remove an element out of the array and shift it down?

Comment: you are awesome. does this similar concept apply when taking an element out and moving it to the end and shifting everything down? also taking an element out and putting it at the start and moving everything up?

Comment: It would be something, but considering that in this case both arrays keep the same size ;-)

Comment: @Tejas, If my answer has been helpful to you, please do not forget to mark it as correct. This may be useful for other developers ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Still working on trying to move an element from an index and put it at the beginning and shift everything else up. I think I understand how to remove an element and put it at the end and shift everything else down.

Comment: A tip. When you move an object to the beginning, for example, from index 5, keep in mind you only have to move objects from 0 to 5, the rest keeps equals. And then, when you move an object from index (5) to last index (data.length - 1), you only have to move object from 5 to "data.length - 1". This can improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your for loop to either:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (i == index){
                temp[index] = el;
                temp[i + 1] = data[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                temp[i] = data[i];
            }

}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i == index){
            temp[index] = el;
            temp[i + 1] = data[i];
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is data.length when the list is empty? If it is empty at first insertion you will not enter the for loop but copy the temp array, it will go into the loop at next insertion with length 1. The first insertion will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
public static void insertElementAt(int index, E el)
    throws IllegalArgumentException {

if (index > data.length || index < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

Object temp[] = new Object[data.length + 1];
for (int i = index; i < data.length; i++) {
    temp[i+1] = data[i];
}
temp[index] = el;
data = temp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should have the test for valid parameters first ("fail early"), and you can make good use of the JDK's utility methods do the lifting for you:

```
public static void insertElementAt(int index, E el) {
    if (index > data.length || index < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + 1);
    System.arrayCopy(data, index, data, index + 1, data.length - index);
    data[index] = el;
}
```

Also note you don't need to declare a `throws`, because`IllegalArgumentException` is an *unchecked* exception, so I removed it. Normally, one follows this pattern.